# How to handle a discount with Corrily's create subscription/charge endpoints

Tags: corrily

Our website is [manually notifying Corrily of subscription and charge events](https://docs.corrily.com/docs/payment-gateway-integration-guide#manually-notify-corrily-of-subscription-and-charge-events). How should we handle discounts?

1. Send the price that the user paid when calling [create subscription](https://docs.corrily.com/reference/create-subscription) and [create charge](https://docs.corrily.com/reference/create-charge)
2. Send the full price and then somehow indicate the discount in a subsequent call(s) to Corrily's API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling create charge/subscription you should pass the price that the user paid. So #1 is the correct approach.

Source: I am currently helping the Corrily team with their documentation. This answer is what the Corrily engineering team told a customer to do.